# Marshall/Unmarshall Map

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

> ```
> @XmlRootElement
> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
> public class ItemSubstitutionRequestDTO {
>     
>     public ItemSubstitutionRequestDTO()
>     {
>         
>     }
>     
>     private List<Map<String,Integer>> substituteFor=new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>();
>   private String orderId;
>   
>   public List<Map<String,Integer>> getSubstituteFor()
>   {
>       return substituteFor;
>   }
>   
>   public void setSubstituteFor(List<Map<String,Integer>> substituteFor)
>   {
>       this.substituteFor = substituteFor;
>   }
>   
>   public String getOrderId() {
>       return orderId;
>   }
>
>   public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
>       this.orderId = orderId;
>   }
>   
> }
> ```

Final result **ERROR**:

> **java.util.Map is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.**

I can't get JaxB to be able to marshall/unmarshall instances of Map.I tried other annotation also and found this is one of the possible way to solve the above error but nothing is woking.

Below is the input json which is coming from UI side

> {     "itemSubstitutionRequestDTO": {         "substituteFor": [{"41712":2}],
> "orderId": "1073901",   } }

Comment: Your example is JSON, not XML. JAXB is suited only for XML. For JSON you would need another framework, may be Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write how your XML content within the
`<substituteFor>` element would look like.
Therefore I assume something like this:

```
<itemSubstitutionRequestDTO>
    <substituteFor>
        <item>
            <key>x</key>
            <value>23</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <key>y</key>
            <value>3</value>
        </item>
    </substituteFor>
    <orderId>abc</orderId>
</itemSubstitutionRequestDTO>
```

As the JAXB error message already told you,
it can't handle types with an interface between the `< >`,
like for example your `List<Map<String,Integer>>`.
However it can handle types with a normal class between `< >`,
like `List<SubstitutionMap>`.

So the first step is to rewrite your `ItemSubstitutionRequestDTO` class
so that it does not use `List<Map<String,Integer>>`, but instead `List<SubstitutionMap>`.
You need to write the `SubstitutionMap` class (not an interface) by yourself.
But it can be extremely simple:

```
public class SubstitutionMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {
}
```

Now JAXB doesn't throw an error anymore, but it still doesn't know how to marshal/unmarshal a `SubstitutionMap`.
Therefore you need to write an [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for it.
Let's call it `SubstitutionMapAdapter`.
To make JAXB aware of this adapter, you need to annotate the `substituteFor`
property in your `ItemSubstitutionRequestDTO` class with:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SubstitutionMapAdapter.class)
```

The adapter's job is to do the actual conversion from `SubstitutionMap`
to an array of `SubstitutionMapElement`s and vice versa.
Then JAXB can handle the `SubstitutionMapElement` array by itself.

```
public class SubstitutionMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<SubstitutionMapElement[], SubstitutionMap> {

    @Override
    public SubstitutionMap unmarshal(SubstitutionMapElement[] elements) {
        if (elements == null)
            return null;
        SubstitutionMap map = new SubstitutionMap();
        for (SubstitutionMapElement element : elements)
            map.put(element.getKey(), element.getValue());
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public SubstitutionMapElement[] marshal(SubstitutionMap map) {
        // ... (left to you as exercise)
    }
}
```

The class `SubstitutionMapElement` is just a simple container for a key and a value.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SubstitutionMapElement {

    private String key;
    private int value;
    
    // ... constructors, getters, setters omitted here for brevity
}
```

Comment: Hey,
Sorry i didnt provided the input ....
I have updated the input which is coming from UI side